# Basic question about labeling of random variables apropos of the definition of convexity

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, convex

I understand the definition of convexity in a function $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ as the inequality for all $a,b\in\mathbb R^d$ and $0<\theta<1:$

$$\theta f(a) + (1-\theta)f(b)        \geq f(\theta a + (1-\theta)b).$$

However, I am confused - likely because I never had formal training - about the index notation in the [definition of convexity](https://www.fooledbyrandomness.com/heuristic.pdf) for random variables:

$$\sum w_i \mathbb E\Big[f(X_i) \Big]\ge \mathbb E\Big[ \sum f(w_i X_i) \Big]$$

Both $X_i$ and $f(X_i)$ are random variables, and [random variables can be indexed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/149878108X).

> So what is $w_i$? I am used to $w$ being weights - like a vector of probabilities, with $i$ in $w_i$ being each specific entry, but that doesn't make sense. I guess the $i$ just refers to the index $i$ of the random variable, which I don't know what differentiating function it has in a general definition. It is an issue of confusion between random variable and specific values of that random variable.

Here is an example of how I would interpret the equation:

```
set.seed(0)
nsim = 10
N = 10 # no. of values to be drawn from the interval [0, 10]
m = matrix(,2,nsim) # Initializing empty matrix

for (i in 1:nsim){
  w = prop.table(runif(N)) # Vector of probabilities (w_i)
  x = sample(seq(0,10,0.00001), N) # Drawing these random values X_1,..., X_N.
  y = x^2 # f(X_i) or payoff function.

  wx = w * x # Dot product <w_i, X_i>
  m[1,i] <- (mean(wx))^2 # Mean squared.

  wy = w * y # Dot product <w_i, f(X_i)>
  m[2,i] <- (mean(wy))^2 # Mean of f(X_i) squared.
}

plot(m[2,], col=5, pch=19, ylim = c(0,10), ylab="Payoff", xlab="Simulation")
points(m[1,], col=2, pch=19)
```

[image]

> Would this be interpreting the notation correctly?

Comment: You are not quoting a definition of random variables, Antoni: that expression is merely a consequence of the *assumed* convexity of the function $f.$ The author has (rather blithely, IMO) assumed the reader understands the $w_i$ are non-negative real numbers that sum to unity.

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much for your comment. I thought what I was quoting was the definition of convexity in the context of random variables. A vector of probabilities adding up to 1 makes a lot of sense, as when trying to find the expectation of a discrete random variable, but I find the index $i$ rather confusing... If it denotes each one of the fractions adding up to 1, does $X_i$ denote the specific values the random variable can take, more typically written as $x_i,$ as in $X=\{1,\dots,6\}$ in for instance $x_5=5$ in a dice?

Comment: Yes, indexing works here exactly the way it works everywhere else: each distinct $i$ designates a random variable.  Taleb's expression is merely a consequence of the definition of convexity you quote and is easily demonstrated inductively: a linear combination of three values is a linear combination of two values, of which one is itself a linear combination, *etc.*

Comment: @whuber Here is where I get stuck... We wouldn't refer to the realization $x_5=5$ of the random variable generated by throwing a dice with probability $w_5=1/6$ as a random variable, but as a possible value of the random variable. It has to be embarrassingly obvious, but I would like to make sure I get it right conceptually, not just intuitively or computationally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's clarify some of the issues.

#### Convexity

Consider a real-valued function function $f$ defined on an interval $I$ of real numbers.  (Everything that follows extends naturally and obviously to functions defined on sets $I\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ *provided* $I$ is a convex set, but I won't belabor that point.  The key property enjoyed by $I$ is that "mixtures" of elements of $I$ are in $I;$ this will be elaborated below.)

$f$ has a *graph* (the set of points $(x,f(x))$ where $x\in I$).  The convexity of $f$ (in the sense given in the question) is equivalent to the graph always "curving upwards." This concept can be made rigorous in various ways; one nice one is that *all points on any line segment connecting any two points on the graph of $f$ lie on or above the graph.*  This is just a geometric restatement of convexity.

> **One consequence of convexity is this:** given any finite number $n$ of points $x_i,$ $i=1,2,\ldots, n$ in $I$ and any set of non-negative numbers ("weights") $w_i$ summing to unity, $$\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\,f(x_i) \ge f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\,x_i\right).\tag{1}$$

(The right hand side is defined because the conditions on the $w_i$ imply the argument of $f$ lies inside $I,$ allowing us to apply $f$ to it.  For brevity, let's call linear combinations where the coefficients are non-negative and sum to unity "mixtures" of the values.)

This figure illustrates the idea of the following proof in the case $n=3:$

[image: Figure]

*The convexity of $f$ is equivalent to all line segments of points on its graph lying within the shaded region on or above its graph (the "epigraph" of $f$).  (That is, the epigraph is a convex region.)  Points on line segments are mixtures of their endpoints.  Mixtures involving $n\gt 2$ points can be considered mixtures of mixtures, making it obvious that they, too, lie in the epigraph. In this figure, the weights are represented by the areas of point symbols.*

**Proof:** Use induction on $n,$ beginning with the "base case" $n=2,$ which is just the defining property of $f.$  Assume hypothetically that $(1)$ holds for a given $n\ge 2$ and all applicable $x_i$ and $w_i.$  Let $x_i$ and $w_i,$ $i=1,2,\ldots, n+1,$ be $n+1$ points in $I$ with $n+1$ weights, respectively.  If the last weight $w_{n+1}$ is zero then (1) applies immediately to the other $n$ points.  It remains to treat the case where $w_{n+1}\ne 0.$  This enables us to focus on the first $n$ weights and renormalize them to sum to unity upon division by $1-w_{n+1}:$

$$\eqalign{
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} w_i\,f(x_i) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i\,f(x_i)  + w_{n+1}\,f(x_{n+1})\\
&= (1-w_{n+1})\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{w_i}{1-w_{n+1}}\,f(x_i)  + w_{n+1}\,f(x_{n+1})\\
&\ge (1-w_{n+1})f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{w_i}{1-w_{n+1}}x_i\right)  + w_{n+1}\,f(x_{n+1})
}$$

by the inductive hypothesis.  But this last expression is a mixture of just *two* values of $f.$  The convexity of $f$ immediately implies

$$\eqalign{
&(1-w_{n+1})f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{w_i}{1-w_{n+1}}x_i\right) + w_{n+1}\,f(x_{n+1})\\ &\ge f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (1-w_{n+1})\frac{w_i}{1-w_{n+1}}x_i + w_{n+1}\,x_{n+1}\right)\\
&= f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} w_i\,x_i\right).
}$$

From the assumption that $(1)$ holds for a particular $n\ge 2$ we have deduced $(1)$ also holds for $n+1.$  Thus, $(1)$ holds for *all* $n\ge 2,$ *QED.*

#### Indexing random variables

Recall that a random variable $X$ is function defined on a set of outcomes $\Omega.$  Let $f$ be the function in the question and let $I$ be its domain.  For expressions like "$f(X)$" to make sense we must assume the image of $X$ is a subset of $I,$ so that we may define the random variable $f(X)$ to be the function on $\Omega$ given by

$$f(X)(\omega) = f(X(\omega))$$

for all $\omega\in\Omega.$  (This is the *composition* of the function $f$ with the function $X.$)

Consider $n$ random variables defined on a common set $\Omega.$  Two hundred years ago, expositors would have described them by naming an indefinite sequence of letters, like this: "Let $A,B,C,\ldots, Z$ be a finite collection of random variables."  Since then, mathematical terminology has evolved toward using *indexing* to give such descriptions.  An "index" is merely an element of a specified set $S,$ often taken to be $S=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ or $S=\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}.$  Our "$n$ random variables" are then described by supposing we are given a function

$$X: S \to \mathcal{R}(\Omega)\tag{2}$$

where $\mathcal{R}(\Omega)$ is the set of random variables defined on $\Omega.$  When we are indexing and $i\in S$ we don't write $X(i)$ for the random variable associated with $i:$ instead, we write $X_i.$  *This is merely a matter of notation; it is not conceptual.*  Thus,

> For each $i\in S,$ $X_i:\Omega\to I$ is a random variable (and these variables are not necessarily distinct).

Often the entire indexed collection of objects is denoted as $(X_i)_{i\in S}.$  This is just another way of writing $(2).$

#### Convexity applied to random variables

Let $f$ be the function in the question, defined on an *interval* $I$ and assumed to be convex  (and measurable), and let $(X_i)_{i\in S}$ be a finite collection of random variables.  Composing $f$ with each $X_i$ produces a random variable $f(X_i):\Omega\to \mathbb{R}.$

Consider any particular outcome $\omega\in\Omega$ and write $x_i = X_i(\omega)$ for each $i\in S.$  We have seen that $f(x_i)=f(X_i(\omega))$ can be considered the value of $f(X_i)$ at $\omega.$ Because $f$ is convex and $x_i\in I,$ for any mixture with coefficients $w_i$ the inequality $(1)$ says

$$\sum_{i\in S} w_i\, f(X_i)(\omega)  = \sum_{i\in S} w_i\, f(x_i) \ge f\left(\sum_{i\in S} w_i\,x_i\right) = f\left(\sum_{i\in S} w_i\,X_i(\omega)\right).$$

Take expectations of both sides with respect to the probability measure defined on $\Omega.$  **Because expectation respects inequalities** (which comes down to the basic and obvious fact that the integral of a non-negative function is a non-negative number), we obtain

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i\in S} w_i\, f(X_i)\right] \ge \mathbb{E}\left[f\left(\sum_{i\in S} w_i\,X_i\right)\right].$$

**Linearity of expectation** lets us re-express the left hand side as

> $$\sum_{i\in S} w_i\, \mathbb{E}\left[f(X_i)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i\in S} w_i\, f(X_i)\right]\ge \mathbb{E}\left[f\left(\sum_{i\in S} w_i\,X_i\right)\right],$$

giving the assertion in the question.

Comment: This is awesome. Your altruism and generosity with your immense knowledge is an inspiration to us all. Thank you. Now it makes perfect sense - upper and lower case $x$ and $\omega$ make a huge difference!